# Duplicate ConEmu git bash tab, and then run command in new tab automatically?

Tags: conemu

I know a **git bash** tab can be properly duplicated, maintaining the CWD, by using

```
ConEmuC -c bash -new_console --login -i
```

I'm attempting to automatically run a command in the new tab, which I've attempted with...

```
ConEmuC -c bash -new_console --login -i && gulp watch
```

But this never runs the command.

Is there a method for doing this? I've gone over the [ConEmu Documentation](http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html) but I don't see anything for running a new command automatically in the new tab.

Comment: http://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartCmd.html

Comment: @Maximus Does this allow you to set a startup command to only run once, in the new tab? Not looking to have a task run every single time I open a new tab.

Comment: @Maximus I'd like to only sometimes run a task on new tab creation, I'm not seeing that in the link provided?

Basically I have a shortcut in my bashrc currently that goes to a project folder, opens up my text editor, runs a git pull and then I want it to open a new tab and run gulp watch.. but only when I use that shortcut. I don't want gulp watch to run every single time I open a tab which seems to be what the link is explaining unless I'm misunderstanding it?